# Flink Python Custom Connector / Source

Tags: java, python, apache-flink, pyflink

I'd like to create a custom user-defined connector / source in pyflink. I see [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/sourceSinks.html) for doing so in Java / Scala but none for Python. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would someone down-vote this? I've done my research, there is no resource clearly explaining if this is possible in Python, or not. I therefore must conclude that either it is possible and not documented, or it's not possible, thus I turn to the community for help.

Comment: Hey, same problem, have you gotten anywhere with this?

Comment: I moved on to using the JVM directly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that part of Flink's API is not available from Python.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a custom connector in Scala and then somehow py4j bridge that over to Python?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure. I suggest you ask on the user mailing list.